# How to view table and database entries from mysql workbench

Tags: php, mysql, database, mysql-workbench

I've been using php and mysql workbench.

Now, I have written the correct necessary code to create/insert into databases and tables.

I have also written code to view and print those entries from a web browser. 
But I want to be able to check and view the entries from the workbench, every time I open the work bench, I seem to have empty databases and tables, but am able to view it from the browser with the php code.

I've tried refreshing the schemas.

Comment: which version of mysql workbench are you using...??

Comment: do you see all your existing tables and db from phpmyadmin or any other db admin panel (apart from workbench) >>

Comment: the only thing I use is workbench. I do not use phpadmin or anything else that is similar to workbench

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First goto

```
Open connection to Start Querying
-> click on New Connection 
-> provide connection name and check credentials to connect to db
-> then click Test Connection if successful click Ok else put the correct credentials.
```

Double click the connection you just created and you'll see all the schemas on the left side.

[image]

[image]

Comment: NOTE: these screenshots are from an old version of MySQL Workbench. See also http://mysqlworkbench.org

Comment: @MikeLischke Thanks but Ebadly.Decipher is using Workbench 5.2.47

Comment: Doesn't that allow a hint about a newer version? And the screenshots are far older than from 5.2.47, hence there are significant differences, even when not using the latest release.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure that you've created a connection and that is working, use `Test connection` will check if its working or not. Then use it to see all your schemas...